# Concurrent / Parallel builds in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

​I was trying to configure the configure parallel builds on my hosted environment. I can see that I've 9 parallel jobs where 1 is free and 8 are Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers. I'm unable to figure it out how can i use the visual studio subscriptions to configure the parallel jobs. [Parallel Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WgLi.png)

Comment: Could you describe more about what you want to achieve by "configure parallel builds", Are you trying to run parallel jobs in your pipeline? Any screenshot you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions count towards your ability to run parallel job's on your Self-hosted agents **not** Microsoft's Hosted Agents.

So for a Private project with your enterprise license count you can run up to 9 jobs at once on your *own* agents that you manage and configure. [See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#self-hosted-cicd).

If you want more concurrent Hosted capacity you will have to [purchase them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-more-build-vs?view=azure-devops#microsoft-hosted-cicd).